# custom buttons on android studio

Tags: android, xml, button

im  new on android studio and i want to  customize my buttons, i created a new xml file on  the folder drawable and I but this code on it (Note: i saw this code in another question) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <stroke
     android:width="1dip"
     android:color="#ffffff"/>
 <solid
     android:color="#95865F"/>
 <corners

     android:topRightRadius="1dp"
     android:bottomRightRadius="1dp"
     android:topLeftRadius="1dp"
     android:bottomLeftRadius="1dp"
     />

 <padding
     android:left="1dp"
     android:right="1dp"
     android:top="1dp"
     android:bottom="1dp"/>
 </shape>
```

this  on muy button  backgroud option i put "@drawable/roundedbutton" that is my xml file name and location also as i saw on other post ,  bus  on the design window i have this text

the graphics preview in the layout editor may not be accurate

and my buttons is now color coffe and ugly!
what should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The color of your button is defined by this property in your xml

```
 <solid
     android:color="#95865F"/>
```

and the color itself is in the hex `RRGGBB` format. If you don't like the color, simply change that value. E.g. `#FF0000` will make your button completely red

Comment: yep , but  when i put that in my code  the color doest change, i think thatits because there is something wrong with the code

Answer (score 0):

In order to set new backgrounds for your buttons you can use:

`<Button
android:layout_widt="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/yourfile"/> <!-- this is for setting the background of a button -->`

But this is just the top of the iceberg.
You can also use the .setText(); method to set a custom text to your button.
More info in here 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html